# Sometimes after I grant a title to a landless councilor, he becomes ineligible for the seat for a while: why?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I've noticed several times that if I have a landless council member and I grant him a landed title, his seat becomes vacant and I cannot appoint him again.

After an unspecified amount of time he becomes eligible again.

Why is that? Is that a bug or is there a reason for that?

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me.  Any direct vassal or courtier should be able to be a councilor.  Some seats do have special restrictions though so maybe you could be more specific about the title and council position?

Comment: @EldritchWarlord next time it happens, I'll document it. Last time it happened when I granted a city to my stewart.

Comment: Is he in hiding?

Comment: @Affine he wasn't. I have a similar problem now, I'll post in greater detail.

Answer (score 4):

I have seen this also. Maybe it's a bug, but if it is it's a fairly minor and predictable one. From what I have seen every time I have ever landed a Courtier Councilor he has been removed from the Council. If I wait a few days I can go back and re-appoint him (or sometimes appoint someone else and get to dodge the 'fired from council' opinion hit). I think I understand why it happens.

All of your councilors are eligible for one of two reasons. Either they are one of your Courtiers, or they are one of your Vassals. When you land a member of your Court he stops being one of your Courtiers and I believe this triggers the game to mark him as ineligible to be on the council and removes him. Of course, he then becomes your Vassal and is eligible once more, but from the game's perspective, the reason he was eligible briefly stopped existing. I suspect that little hiccup when the councilor eligibility changes causes him to be removed.

Comment: When I did that, I still got the "fired from council" negative opinion.

Comment: BTW I'll have a closer look next time it happens.

Comment: Yah, I've noticed this happening and I just reappoint him to the position. I not sure if they end having the fire from council negative opinion. It's not something I would've noticed since the bonus for giving the title plus the bonus for being on the council will be greater. There still would've been a net opinion gain.

Comment: I could see it as your councilor takes a brief vacation to go check out their new holdings and organize their own court, but it's still annoying that you can hold the job for them until they return.

Comment: I've noticed a few other bugs relating to delayed effect of titles changing hands. One of my favorite and most useful ones is that a characters income does not change immediately when they receive a title. The amount for a gift is dependent on a characters income, so if you notice a succession take place, you can usually sneak in a really cheap bribe/gift for your new vassal, usually only 20 gold if they were landless prior to the switch.